# Prime number sieve using difference of two squares

Tags: performance, primes, pari-gp

Here is a working pari/gp implementation of prime number sieve. Is there something that I could change in code to achieve a better running time?

```
Sieve(g)=
{
A=vector(floor((g-1)/2));
for(n=1,floor((g-1)/2),
   A[n]=2*n+1);
for(x=3,floor(sqrt(g)),
   if(Mod(x,2)==1,i=0,i=1);
   forstep(y=i,x-3,[2],
      A[(x^2-y^2-1)/2]=0));
for(x=ceil(sqrt(g)),ceil((g+9)/6),
   i=ceil(sqrt(x^2-g));
   if(Mod(x+i,2)==0,i=i+1);
   forstep(y=i,x-3,[2],
      A[(x^2-y^2-1)/2]=0));
A=concat(2,A);
for(j=0,floor((g-1)/2),
   if(!(A[j+1]==0),print(A[j+1])))
}
```

Comment: Does this only calculate Mersenne primes?

Comment: @varfirstName  With this prime number sieve you can find all the prime numbers up to any given limit greater than one .

Comment: Check if the prime is less than pg's prime generator's maximum and just run that function if it is.

Comment: avoid multiple calls of sqrt(g) by local variable

Answer (score 3):

Good comments make code more maintainable. I had to reverse engineer what this code was doing, when a few comments could have made it clear.

---

For my taste the code could use a lot more whitespace, but I'm going to try to stick to your style in the proposed changes.

---

Separation of responsibilities: it would be cleaner to return a vector rather than to "return" with `print`.

---

There's a lot in common between the two main loops:

> ```
> for(x=3,floor(sqrt(g)),
>    if(Mod(x,2)==1,i=0,i=1);
>    forstep(y=i,x-3,[2],
>       A[(x^2-y^2-1)/2]=0));
> for(x=ceil(sqrt(g)),ceil((g+9)/6),
>    i=ceil(sqrt(x^2-g));
>    if(Mod(x+i,2)==0,i=i+1);
>    forstep(y=i,x-3,[2],
>       A[(x^2-y^2-1)/2]=0));
> ```

It might clarify things to refactor them into one:

```
for(x=3,floor((g+9)/6),
  forstep(y=x-3,0,-2,
    if(x^2-y^2>g,break);
    A[(x^2-y^2-1)/2]=0
  ));
```

Note that this fixes an out-by-one in the upper bound of `x`.

Now I'm ready to look at performance. The low-hanging fruit here is `x^2-y^2`: it's usually faster to calculate a constant product or square of a loop index by addition. I'm also going to use bitwise operations for multiplication and division by 2 because that means not having to worry about how clever the compiler is.

```
for(x=3,floor((g+9)/6),
  d=(x<<1)-1;
  forstep(y=x-3,0,-2,
    d+=(y+1)<<2;
    if(d>g,break);
    A[d>>1]=0
  ));
```

You should easily be able to prove the invariant that `d == x^2 - y^2`, and since it's odd `(d-1)/2 == d>>1`. In fact, we can instead work with `(x^2-y^2)>>1`:

```
cap=(g-1)>>1;
for(x=3,floor((g+9)/6),
  d=x-1;
  forstep(yp=(x-2)<<1,2,-4,
    d+=yp;
    if(d>cap,break);
    A[d]=0
  ));
```

With Try It Online! and pushing towards the size limit for allocation of `A` I see a speedup from 4.4s (user) to [3.5s](https://tio.run/##VY/BCoMwDIbvPkWPzWyxdWNQNILPsKN4cLOKbGhxIsrYs7uoY7BL@JP/@0Piir6RtVuWS2NHy2tA7@WlONrb0PW8enRUeS01BCFA5FXUtqjFvyFYmrU5hofW1wTdCoeblSR6j0x4/EV8A8EZhMdYiZMkgDFCnoN1fKbcJEOIYy1CIU8rRJiPs4s22VS8TGi9uPa2uMM@TLMyR0VyPfD9fUQbY5RSsHwA). (Output removed for timing purposes. Timings available by expanding the "Debug" section).

---

Other optimisations:

1. If the vector is just initialised as `vector((g-1)>>1)` then it will initially contain `0` at all indices. Then change `A[d]=0` to `A[d]=1` and change the logic in the output loop.
2. Ditch the `concat` and output `2` as a special case.

Beyond that, you need to look at different algorithms. The binary quadratic form `x^2-y^2` doesn't seem to be a common one in prime sieving. You could see how it compares with Sundaram's sieve (BQF `x+y+2xy`) or failing that, if you're working with large enough ranges, Atkin-Bernstein (e.g. a combination of `3x^2+y^2`, `4x^2+y^2`, `5x^2+3y^2`, `15x^2+y^2`, and `3x^2-y^2` for different totients of 60).